# C pipe bad value from parent proccess

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have this simple program, but when I wanted to check the value that I get from the child it returns 1995694080 or similiar numbers. I'm a bit confused, how can I achieve to get the real value of msg? It looks like I'm getting some random trash value from somewhere else where I'm not supposed to. I made this pipe sendier based on a tutorial, and it's mostly works just when I'm sending back the data from the child it fails. Any idea or suggestion?

```
int pipefd[2];

int main()
{
    signal(SIGTERM, handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, finishedOrder);
    pid_t pid;


    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error while making pipe.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid > 0)
    {
        employer(pid, 4, false);
    }
    else
    {
        employee(getppid());
    }
}

void employer(pid_t pid, int id, bool two)
{
    int rec;

    printf("[Szülő]: várok egy szerelő csapatra! \n");
    sleep(1);

    kill(pid, SIGTERM);

    pause();

    if (two)
    {
        /.../
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[Szülő]: dolgozz a %d. feladaton\n", id);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(pipefd[1], &id, sizeof(id)); //this is works.
        close(pipefd[1]);
        sleep(1);

        kill(pid, SIGTERM);

        pause();

        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    }

    pause();

    close(pipefd[1]);
    read(pipefd[0], &rec, sizeof(rec));

    printf("%d\n", rec); // here I get the strange value

    if (rec == 4)
    {
        printf("[Szülő]: feljegyeztem a módosításokat.\n");
        if (two)
        {
            /**/
        }
        else
        {
            /**/
        }
    }

}

void employee(pid_t emp)
{
    int jobs[2];
    pause();

    printf("[Gyerek]: munkára jelentkezek\n");
    sleep(1);

    kill(emp, SIGTERM);

    pause();

    close(pipefd[1]);

    read(pipefd[0], &jobs[0], sizeof(jobs[0]));
    close(pipefd[0]);
    printf("[Gyerek]: elkezdek dolgozni a %d. feladaton.\n", jobs[0]);
    sleep(1);
    kill(emp, SIGUSR1);
    pause();

    sleep(1);
    read(pipefd[0], &jobs[1], sizeof(jobs[1]));


    if (jobs[1] != 0)
    {
        printf("[Gyerek]: elkezdek dolgozni a %d. feladaton.\n", jobs[1]);
        sleep(1);

        kill(emp, SIGUSR1);
    }

    close(pipefd[0]);
    fflush(NULL);
    int msg = 4;
    printf("%d\n", msg);
    write(pipefd[1], &msg, sizeof(msg));
    close(pipefd[1]);

    sleep(1);
    kill(emp, SIGTERM);
}

void handler(int signum)
{
}

void finishedOrder()
{
}
```

Comment: Maybe that `read` didn't succeed? How would you know if you ignore its return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
read(pipefd[0], &rec, sizeof(rec));
```

You don't check the value returned by `read` to see how much data you've received. If you did, you'll probably find that it is not what you expect because earlier on in your code you did this...

```
    close(pipefd[0]);
```

You can't read from a file descriptor after you've closed it. And somewhat more importantly, the "pipe" you created isn't bi-directional. If you want to send and receive, you need to do two calls to `pipe` to get two pairs of file descriptors.

Given that you also do `close(pipefd[1])` before the `read` which means that you've closed both ends of the pipe, it looks like you've misunderstood what the purpose of `close`ing is for in this context. The child and parent `close` the end of the pipe that they're not using - that's it. It doesn't signify anything about who is reading or writing to the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

In your `employer()` function, you close the read end of the pipe with `close(pipefd[0]);` then try to read from it later with `read(pipefd[0], &rec, sizeof(rec));`

Trying to read from a closed fd <del>probably causes weird values.</del> will do what Johnathan Leffler says it will do.

rustyx is right in the comments - checking the return value of `read()` is good idea, because it would uncover this kind of error.

Comment: Reading from a closed fd simply causes the read to fail rather quickly — return value is -1 and errno is EBADF.  It doesn't modify the array passed to hold the data.  The code doesn't, but should, check the return values from read and write.